# String replacing of a path entered : "\" to "/"

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Consider the following code:

```
class Sample{
public static void main(String args[]){
    String text1="C:\Documents\User\sample";

    String text2=text1.replace('\','/');

    System.out.println(text2);
        }
}
```

I have an input where the text1 is receiving a file path. Now I want to replace all the "\" in text1 to "/". I have used the code above.

First of all, the error shown is : "Illegal Escape Sequence" which is understandable and is not my issue because I am making a Java EE application where the user enters the path in the input box.

But I have trouble changing the "\" into "/" which is essential for my code to run properly. I am not able to solve this problem. I have even tried using String.replaceAll() method, but no result.

Comment: replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)  is for strings while yours is for charSequence

Comment: Can you try ("\\",'/') ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash:

```
String text2=aa.replace('\\','/');
```

By the way, `replaceAll()` would make your problem even more complicated: Now you're dealing with a regex instead of a simple string replace, and that means your backslashes need to be escaped yet again for the regex engine:

```
String text2=aa.replaceAll("\\\\", "/");
```

Answer (score 2):

`\` is an escape character in java strings, you will need to escape it by doing `\\`, this will prevent it from escaping the `'` next to it, and solve your error.
This would turn your line of code into:

```
String text2 = text1.replace('\\', '/');
```

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html) is a good example of how this character can normally be used.

From the looks of it, you might be better off doing the following too:

```
String text1="C:\\Documents\\User\\sample";
```

instead of replacing after the string is initialised.

Comment: Very good point about the wrongly specified path! The current one may work, but `"C:\Documents\User\new"` will fail spectacularly.

Comment: @Serdalis: Thanks . But my situation is that i am creating a webpage where the user enters the path in the said format(c:\documents\user\sample).

Comment: @Rishu: When the user enters the path, the backslashes will automatically be doubled. So serdalis' or my solution will work correctly.